# Rust: no method named `iter` found for struct `std::ops::Range<usize>` in the current scope

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, range

Could you please tell me what is the compiler complaining about? I dont get it.

```
numcities is a usize
let mut path = (0..graph.numcities).chain([0].iter()).collect();


error[E0599]: no method named `iter` found for struct `std::ops::Range<usize>` in the current scope
   --> tsp-arekbulski-01-random.rs:230:39
    |
230 |         let mut path = (0..graph.numcities).iter().chain([0].iter()).collect();
    |                                             ^^^^ method not found in `std::ops::Range<usize>`
```

Comment: Your code and error do not match. Could you make a reproducible example on https://play.rust-lang.org?

Comment: range is already an iterator

Answer (score 1):

I believe this was the solution/workaround:

```
let mut path: Vec::<usize> = (0..graph.numcities).collect::<Vec::<usize>>().iter().chain([0].iter()).map(|x| *x).collect();
```